# Active link not working in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Hi I need some help with an active link not working in my wordpress theme. In the blog archive page I made some buttons to divide the archives blogs in sub categories however the active pseudo not working.

The php i'm using to get the subcategories list is

```
<div class="archive-subcategories">
  <?php $subcategories = get_categories('&child_of=5&hide_empty'); 
    echo '<ul class="resource-subcategory">';
    foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
    echo sprintf('<li class="sub-category">
    <a class="link-active" href="%s">%s</a></li>', get_category_link
    ($subcategory->term_id), apply_filters('get_term', $subcategory->name));
    }
    echo '</ul>'; 
  ?>
</div>
```

I've tried a few options but with no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think there is no problem with your code, it should work. Are you sure about the category id of 5?

Comment: Yes, the code is good I get the sub categories i want but when I add the active css pseudo it doesn't work. I cannot figure out why.

Comment: your question isn't related to Wordpress. It's better to make a jsfiddle version of your output. It will be more helpful